# Complex MySQL Query for related users and posts

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

I have a need to build a MySQL query to notify users of a software package when a comment is added to a post. The tables I have for this are

> **Posts**: pid, uid
>
> **Comments**: cid, uid, pid
>
> **Users**: uid
>
> **Related**: rid, uid1, uid2
>
> **Devices**: did, uid

A post can have many comments, many comments can be posted per user, and a user may have many devices.

When a comment is inserted I need to get a list of unique devices for everyone who has contributed to the comments for the moment including the author but only where they are related to the user who has commented.

the

> redlated.uid1

holds the userid and

> related.uid2

holds their related userid e.g.

```
-----------------------------------
| rid       |  uid1      |  uid2  |
-----------------------------------
| 1         |  34        |  43    |
-----------------------------------
| 2         |  43        |  34    |
-----------------------------------
```

I have available the following data

> **PostAuthorId** | **PostID**  | **UserID**

Can anyone help I am struggling to get the right data out all queries thus far have been wrong, i have not posted one as I think it could confuse even further.

As i said I need to return only unique devices, any help would be awesome thanks

EDIT SQLFIDDLE ****

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4217f

---

Comment: Can you please add all of the relavent MySQL table columns?

Comment: > **Posts**: pid, uid
> **Comments**: cid, uid, pid 
> **Users**: uid 
> **Related**: rid, uid1, uid2
> **Devices**: did, uid devices.did is ultimately what I am looking to return

Comment: *for everyone who has contributed to the comments* - how do I know which uses contributed to a comment? Is that in a separate table?

Comment: @JustinErswell, it'd be better if you show us your tables structure. You can use http://sqlfiddle.com for this

Comment: Can you explain how "related" works?  Which of the two user ids would map back to the user id on the posts or to the one on devices?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4217f

Comment: Related works as it created a relation ship between two users each user will have an entry for their related users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is one correct (multi) JOIN

```
SELECT ...
FROM Posts P
INNER JOIN Users O ON P.uid = O.uid  -- Post owner
INNER JOIN Devices OD ON O.uid = OD.uid  -- Devices of post owner
INNER JOIN Related R ON O.uid = R.uid1  -- Post owner to other user relationship
INNER JOIN Comments C ON R.uid2 = C.uid AND P.pid = C.pid  -- Comments by related user
INNER JOIN Devices CD ON C.uid = CD.uid  -- Devices of users posting comments
WHERE pid = yourPostID
```

this should do it.
Don't forget that you have Devices table twice so you have to refer to them via OD (owner's) and CD (comment poster's) devices

Comment: This looks good however it is not returning the original post authors device @germann-arlington

Comment: @Justin Erswell Add another JOIN for 
`INNER JOIN Devices D1 ON P.uid = D1.uid`

Comment: unfortunately i get the same result am I missing something? could you update your answer, really appreciate your time

Comment: @JustinErswell Try my updated SQL (in the post) and make sure that you refer to correct table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct d.did from devices d where d.uid in
(select c.uid from comments c where 
c.pid = (select c.pid from comments c where c.cid=@recently_inserted_cid)
union
(select p.uid from posts p where 
p.pid = (select c.pid from comments c where c.cid=@recently_inserted_cid))
)
and d.uid in 
(select r.uid2 from related r where r.uid1 = 
(select c.uid from comments c where     c.cid=@recently_inserted_cid))
```